# How to get data when foreign key value store as array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-queue

I have two tables where the base `user` table `id` column as primary key and child table `user_report` has a foreign key `user_id`.

I know that this is not good way to store value as array. But I just want to know that for current scenario.

Table1: `user`

- `id`
- `name`
- `email`

Table2: `user_report`

- `id`
- `user_id` ( value store as array like `[1,2,4]` )

Now the question is how can I easily retrieve user report data with user data with single query.

So far I have tried as below.

```
$report = UserReport::find( $id );
$users = User::whereIn( 'id', $report ->user_id )->get()->toArray();
```

I hope someone can help to solve this problem. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not do it that way. Normalize your table, `user_reports`, where the `user_id` is only ONE id, but then you rather have multiple rows. That way you can use Laravel relations - more smooth and easier to work with.

Comment: @Qirel In the question he says he knows it's not the right way of handeling things.  But I agree it's better to change the db structure and create relationships

Comment: @Qirel Thanks for the suggestion, I know that but just want to know how can achieve this way.

Comment: You can't reduce that to a single query without making it overly complex, because you need to retrieve it and split on it first.  With a normalized table, like I said before, you can do it in a single query.

Comment: @Qirel Yes, I just want to know that is it possible or not. I got the answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the user_id attribute to an array:

```
$users = User::whereIn( 'id', explode(',',$report ->user_id) )->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: In my question, I have tried two queries and it is working fine. But how can improve the above query with single query

Comment: If you use comma separated ids you should not do it in one query. Thats one of the  reasons why you should use relationships instead. Well you can, but that would mean a slow complicated query.

Comment: Thanks. So the conclusion is not possible with this DB structure.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to have multiple queries. Eloquent does load some relationships with multiple queries too, just because it's more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this kind of solution in your project. Because foreign key relation dont have multiple values like [1,2,3...] in one record.

**Table1: user**

```
id
name
email
```

**Table2: report**

```
id,
detail
```

**Table3: user_report**

```
id
report_id
user_id
```